# MYSQL bulk INSERT slow

Tags: mysql, performance, bulkinsert

I have a MYSQL INSERT that is very very long.
MYSQL freezes for some minutes and after unfreeze no data has been inserted.

Is there something wrong with my INSERT query?

```
INSERT INTO polim_inventory_transactions 
(item, type, warehouse, quantity, date) 
VALUES
(100004, 'Inventory Tr', 'BFL', 354.0000, '2013-01-31'),
(100007, 'Purchase Rec', 'BFL', 23552.0000, '2013-01-15'),
(100206, 'Inventory Tr', 'BFL', 125.0000, '2013-01-08'),
(100206, 'Inventory Tr', 'BFL', 75.0000, '2013-01-09'),
(100206, 'Inventory Tr', 'BFL', 100.0000, '2013-01-09'), ....
```

Comment: do you have many index added on the table? because too much indexes could slow `INSERT`, `UPDATE` and `DELETE` statement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If this is MyISAM table than you can try locking it before insert.
Also, if you have keys on this table, disabling them can be helpful too:

```
ALTER TABLE polim_inventory_transactions DISABLE KEYS;
```

In general, you can see more tips here: [Bulk Data Loading for MyISAM Tables](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/optimizing-myisam-bulk-data-loading.html)

Comment: Thank you! Disabling keys did the trick. Now the query executes under 3 seconds.

Comment: Note: you need to enable keys after INSERT is finished. This is the stage that takes time if you have many/large keys.